# Session won't set with AJAX call

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have to put session using AJAX call.

This is my AJAX:

```
$('#langgg, .menuAnchor').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var route = "{{route('setto')}}";
    $.ajax({
        url:route,
        type:'post',
        success:function(data){
            location.href = self.href;
        },
    });
});
```

And I think it works pretty fine.

Here's my method:

```
public function setto(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
         $request->session()->put('langg','en');
        // Session::put('langg'=>'ar');
        // session(['lang'=>'ar']);
        return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
    }
}
```

The return is correct but when I get the session it didn't work!!

Comment: Is it a cross-origin ajax call?

Comment: i dont know what you mean !! , it's normal ajax

Comment: I mean, is your frontend on the same host as your backend? like http://localhost:8000

Comment: i m working on local host

Comment: Yes, but localhotst can have many ports, and often the frontend is served by a dev-server on a different port. To make things short: Is your JS code within your laravel app? If not, sessions will not work for you, because cookies aren't transferred between different domains.

Comment: the laravel method return object, but how i know that ?
but it's in same project

Comment: `when i get the session` - how do you get it?  `it didn't work` - what happened?